# Работа с фаилами в Си

Tags: c, файлы

Требование: объединить два файла в третий, имя которого задается клавиатурой. Содержимое файла отображается на экране. 
Я пытался сделать программу, но данные в файле не копируются, и я не могу найти ошибку. Кто-то поможет мне, пожалуйста

#include 
    #include

```
int main()
{
    FILE * fpointer;
    FILE * fpointer2;
    FILE * fpointer3;
    char name[50];
        printf("file 1 :\n");
    fpointer = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    char singleLine[1500];

    while(!feof(fpointer)){
        fgets(singleLine, 1500, fpointer);
        puts(singleLine);
    }
printf("\n");
printf("file 2 :\n");
        fpointer2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
    char singleLine2[1500];

    while(!feof(fpointer2)){
        fgets(singleLine2, 1500, fpointer2);
        puts(singleLine2);
    }



    printf("name new file: ");
    scanf("%s",name);


    fpointer3=fopen(name,"w");
   char c;

   if (fpointer == NULL || fpointer2 == NULL || fpointer3 == NULL)
   {
         puts("Could not open files");
         exit(0);
   }


   while ((c = fgetc(fpointer)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fpointer3);


   while ((c = fgetc(fpointer2)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fpointer3);

  fclose(fpointer2);
    fclose(fpointer);
    fclose(fpointer3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Наверное лучше сначала спросить имя третьего файла и выводить на экран содержимое первых 2-х одновременно с копированием их символов в 3-й файл

Comment: Уже справился спасибо))) Там было очени просто, я просто после закрытие фаилов прописал строку чтобы их афишировати ))) сработало

Comment: "Aфишировати"? Вам нужно было просто перемотать файлы на начало после первого чтения. Что еще удивляет безмерно, так это проверка на успешность открытия файлов, которая стоит *после* их чтения O_o

Comment: Для домашки соидет и так)

Comment: как сравнить два стека c общими данные???